# Does XmlSerializer support property name changes (version tolerant)

Tags: c#, properties, version, xmlserializer

I have

```
public bool Included { get; set; }
```

That I want to change to:

```
public bool IsIncluded { get; set; }
```

I want to have backward compatibility. I'd like to only have IsIncluded defined in code but being able to read old xml where the property would be "Included".

Does XmlSerializer support it and how ?

Note: I tried without success... (does not deserialize it)

```
    public bool IsIncluded { get; set; }

    [Obsolete]
    public bool Included
    {
        set { IsIncluded = value; }
        get { return IsIncluded; }
    }
```

**Update** I just want to add that I prefer my solution because I wanted that my xml become IsIncluded which, to me, is more appropriate. Doing as I did (solution below), would enable me to change the xml but keeping previous version working fine. In long term, I would probably be able to remove code to support old version.

**Update 2018-02-01** Please take a look at Greg Petersen comment below solution and proposed solution. He propose a great solution in order to encapsulate the correction at the place (the class) where it should be done. WOW!!!

Comment: Are you asking if .. can rename the property?  And it be "backwards compatible" ?

Comment: Oops... I want to have backward compatibility. I'd like to only have IsIncluded but being able to read old xml where the field was "Included". Thanks. I added more precision in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it. This is how I did it.

```
// ******************************************************************
public static SimulScenario LoadFromFile(string path)
{
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        return new SimulScenarioError(path);
    }

    SimulScenario simulScenario = null;
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(path);
    XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SimulScenario));

    x.UnknownAttribute +=x_UnknownAttribute;
    x.UnknownElement += x_UnknownElement;
    x.UnknownNode += x_UnknownNode;
    x.UnreferencedObject += x_UnreferencedObject;

    try
    {
        simulScenario = (SimulScenario)x.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return new SimulScenarioError(path);
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.Close();
    }

    return simulScenario;
}

static void x_UnreferencedObject(object sender, UnreferencedObjectEventArgs e)
{

}

static void x_UnknownNode(object sender, XmlNodeEventArgs e)
{

}

static void x_UnknownElement(object sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    var simulChangeState = e.ObjectBeingDeserialized as SimulChangeState;
    if (simulChangeState != null)
    {
        if (e.Element.Name == "Included")
        {
            bool val;
            if (bool.TryParse(e.Element.InnerText, out val))
            {
                simulChangeState.IsIncluded = val;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new FileFormatException(Log.Instance.AddEntry(LogType.LogError, "Invalid scenario file format."));
            }
        }
    }
}

static void x_UnknownAttribute(object sender, XmlAttributeEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Great solution.  I created an interface with a function to to be called when the element was not found.  Then you simply need to add this interface to any class you are deserializing.  Then just check if e.ObjectBeingDeserialized is that interface and call the function if it is.  This encapsulates the correction in the object that has been changed.

Comment: Wow great way to encapsulate the correction at the right place (hi cohesion - low coupling). I really like it. I will keep in mind for future serialization. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Try out:

```
[XmlElement("Included")]
public bool IsIncluded { get; set; }
```

---

Example. Serialization of v1.c and deserialzation of v2.c:

```
namespace v1
{
    public class c
    {
        public bool Included { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace v2
{
    public class c
    {
        [XmlElement("Included")]
        public bool IsIncluded { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            new XmlSerializer(typeof(v1.c)).Serialize(sw, new v1.c{ Included=true} );

            StringReader sr = new StringReader( sw.ToString() );
            v2.c cc = (v2.c)new XmlSerializer(typeof(v2.c)).Deserialize(sr);

            Debug.Assert(cc.IsIncluded);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @Jeff, Hi Jeff, that is only used to change name. I can't read the old value on old version using your suggestion.

Comment: Hi, Eric. If I get you right, you want to deserialize an instance of new class from the old xml. I added code sample to demonstrate it.

Comment: @use3967979, Yes and no... I want to be able to deserialize from old xml but I do not want to create different namespace for each version. Also, the class is part of a big hierarchy of classes. Creating a namespace for each version is unmanageable. I think my solution is not the best because the version control should have been done locally in the class itself instead of load/save function. A better approach would be to do it locally in the class because nobody else need to know that an attribute had been renamed.

Comment: Namespaces are just to avoid naming collision in the sample. You don't have to put your class in new namespace in production code.

Answer (score 2):

I used Eric's solution with a few modifications.  I added an interface class to handle the backward compatibility portion.

```
public interface IBackwardCompatibilitySerializer
{
    void OnUnknownElementFound(string uknownName, string value);
}
```

Using this, we need to write the unknown element event only once like this

```
private static void x_UnknownElement(object sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    var deserializedObj = (e.ObjectBeingDeserialized as IBackwardCompatibilitySerializer);
    if (deserializedObj == null) return;
    deserializedObj.OnUnknownElementFound(e.Element.Name, e.Element.InnerText);
}
```

Then, for any class where you want to change a variable name, have it implement the interface.  Your class would then look like this

```
public class MyClass : IBackwardCompatibilitySerializer 
{
    // public bool Included { get; set; } Old variable

    public bool IsIncluded { get; set; } // New Variable

    public void OnUnknownElementFound(string unknownElement, string value) 
    {
         switch(unknownElement)
         {
              case "Included":
                    IsIncluded = bool.Parse(value);
                    return;
         }
    }
}
```

Eric, feel free to incorporate this into your solution if you like.