# Is there a standard for converting OO objects to and from XML?

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization, versioning

I am looking to implement XML serialisation in .net, but encode the objects manually to ensure I can manage versioning.

Objects tend have individual instances of child objects, as well as arrays, dictionaries and tuples of them, each of which seem to change the ideal storage structure for them. Starting with the object `A`:

```
Class A
  Private b as B
  private c as C
  private d as B
  private e as List(Of B)
  private f as Dictionary(of Integer, C)
End Class
```

made up of:

```
Class B
  dim x as Integer
End Class

Class C
  dim y as String
End Class
```

`B` when serialised could appear as:

```
<B x=1/>
```

and `C` as

```
<C y="Foo"/>
```

`B` in a list may benefit from an index number

```
<B id=23 x=1/>
```

and `C` in a dictionary from a key

```
<C key="Bar" y="Foo"/>
```

Now `A` has two instances of B, so the instances could do with an instance name:

```
<A>
  <B instanceName="b" x=1/>
  <C instanceName="c" y="Foo"/>
  <B instanceName="d" x=2/>
  <List type="B" instanceName="e">
    <B id=0 x=3/>
    <B id=1 x=4/>
  </List>
  <Dictionary keyType="Integer" valueType="C" instanceName="f">
    <C key=0 y="Bar"/>
    <C key=14 y="Baz"/>
  </Dictionary>
</A>
```

In every place where an 'object' is encoded, it requires different attributes to identify it, whereas I would like each object to have its own encapsulated XML definition, while not being excessively bulky. I have imagined some other ways of serialising such as:

```
<InstanceName type=typeName attributes...>
```

however this does not do well with an array:

```
  <List type="B" instanceName="e">
    <0 type="B" x=3/>
    <1 type="b" x=4/>
  </List>
```

as the element names are now index numbers. Something like:

```
<A>
  <Instance name="b">
    <B x=1/>
  </Instance>
  <Instance name="c">
    <C y="Foo"/>
  </Instance>
  <Instance name="d">
    <B x=2/>
  </Instance>
  <Instance name="e">
    <List type="B" instanceName="e">
      <Element id=0>
        <B x=3/>
      </Element>
      <Element id=0>
        <B x=4/>
      </Element>
    </List>
  </Instance>
  <Instance name="f">
    <Dictionary keyType="Integer" valueType="C">
      <Element>
        <Key>0</Key>
        <Value>
          <C y="Bar"/>
        </Value>
      </Element>
      <Element>
        <Key>14</Key>
        <Value>
          <C y="Baz"/>
        </Value>
      </Element>
    </Dictionary>
  </Instance>
</A>
```

meets the need but seems exceptionally bloated. I feel like this problem must have a very standard solution that I'm missing.

Comment: I'm curious _why_ you want to reinvent the wheel - I guess it has something to do with the desire to "manage versioning".  Can you expand on what "manage versioning" means in your question, and why the existing options for XML serialization don't work for your needs?  (You've looked at how the [.NET XML serializer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/introducing-xml-serialization) works, right?  Have you explored how to control it by [using attributes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes)?)

Comment: I have had experience with the .net binary serializer and found it exceptionally good but 1) very slow and 2) very brittle in the face of versioning. I have not explored the XML serializer any further suspecting the same kinds of limitations. On versioning, if I don't know exactly how it has formatted the file, then if the object format changes over time to newer versions, it can be borderline impossible to open an old file - at least in my experience.

Comment: Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20689605/3791245) to a similar question to see one idea for solving versioning in XML serialization.  XML formatting is very flexible, assuming you are willing to put in some work.  Another approach is to have your object classes that can change over time implement [IXMLSerializable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable?view=netcore-3.1), and override the ReadXml/WriteXml methods.  You can then step through the XML nodes, find a version attribute, and pick and choose how to deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I've no answer, merely observations.

Your last para, "meets the need but seems exceptionally bloated", says pretty much everything about XML (or indeed any other text wireformat). Fundamentally, they all have to solve the same problem of describing structure and content, and if that is to be readable the wireformat is going to have to use keywords that have meaning and symbols that denote scope. The more features in the wireformat, the greater the number of keywords and symbols required. So bloat is pretty much unavoidable.

One could make a wireform that appears less bloated by using whitespace instead of symbols (much like Python does). But it won't then be XML.

One could also imagine a wireformat where "Element" and "Instance" were replaced by 'E' and 'I' and so on, but then you're part way to a binary wireformat. Replace the types and values with binary representations too, and...

**Tools**

The objectionable nature of bloat in a text wireformat stems from two concerns; it looks inefficient for the computer to handle all that text, and it's painful to have to plough through it manually in a text editor.

Sadly, the first of these seldom seems to be an issue to many developers, and I suppose that's inevitable when CPU cycles, network bandwidth and storage capacity is so cheap. You have to get really big before you're forced to address this, and indeed these were the reasons Google developed Google Protocol Buffers. The irony of GPB was that there was already a solution out there, Google's engineers never used their own search engine to go look for it...

The second one, the appearance of the data in a text editor, is more interesting. People have developed folding text editors that can cope with, for example, scopes in XML. Useful, but still pretty bloated, cumbersome, etc.

What very few developers get to experience is the commercial tooling that exists for ASN.1 (the thing Google hadn't heard of before they developed GPB). I have, and both major vendors provide a data viewing application, or Visual Editors for the wireformat (well, all the ASN.1 wireformats, including XER which is an XML representation and JSON).

**Visual Editors**

These are superb; in effect, from the serialisation schema one has written, the Visual Editor creates a GUI (an exaplandable tree) that allows one to explore, search, and edit content in sensible ways. For example, if a field in a structure is an INTEGER with a constrained value, somewhere in the object tree there's a box that you can type a value into, and it won't let you type in a value outside the constraint. Same for text, floats, binary strings, and so forth.

My point is that concerns over bloat, readability, appearance, text wireformats, are all just skirting round a more fundamental issue; a lack of a tool designed to do the job properly. In the ASN.1 world these tools do exist (for a price). It's a much better experience than using a folding text editor for the same purpose.

These tools are also very useful in the communications world (which is where ASN.1 came from), because they show you the consequence of a schema in terms of wireformat size, showing you what each particular field looks like in wireformat (be that BER, u/a/c PER, JSON, XML, DER, etc). If one is looking to minimise the number of bits used (which on a radio link you normally are), this is a real productivity booster. You never really appreciate just how clever ASN.1's constraints and uPER are until you see how few bits it needs to get information packaged up. Not bad for the 1980s.